# How do I get correct results to search a string like 1,2,3,4,5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say my database value something like this

```
user_id  question_id
---------------------
1        1,2,3,4,5
2        3,4,5
3        1,3,5
4        3,4,5,6,7
```

What is correct statement to find which user exactly using `question_id` `1 & 5`

```
$query = '1,5';

question_id LIKE '%" . $query . "%'
FIND_IN_SET(question_id,'" . $query . "')
question_id IN ('" . $query . "')
```

I tried using `LIKE`, `FIND_IN_SET` & `IN` but the result is incorrect.

So I want the result should be

```
user_id  question_id
---------------------
1        1,2,3,4,5
3        1,3,5
```

Let me know..

Comment: Where does any best practice say "store data as a CSV"?

Comment: You should normalize, and each user can have multiple question id.

Comment: @ajreal +1 yes.. the thing should I learn.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$query = '1,5';
 parse this into two variables

```
$query1 = '1';

$query2 = '5';
```

now create query dynamically

```
FIND_IN_SET('" . $query1 . "', question_id) AND FIND_IN_SET('" . $query2 . "', question_id)
```

Comment: Thanks & the result is not found

Comment: thats because probably syntax of find_in_set that you were using was wrong. I have edited the answer, please see that. @MRA

Comment: Thanks Zohaib.. You just made my day.